# Уравнение из массива чисел

Tags: java, math

Пользователь вводит числа и скобки через пробел (на каждую открытую скобку всегда есть закрытая). Например `18 7 ( 5 3 ) 2`.
Алгоритм должен составить из этого набора нормальное уравнение и выдать `18=7+(5-3)*2`
Есть только +,-,*,=, другие действия не используются.
Порядок действий в уравнении не стандартный - вначале то, что в скобках, а потом слева направо. Например 3+3*5 будет 30.

Язык не важен, главное придумать сам алгоритм.
Есть у кого какие-то идеи ?

Comment: Перебор, какие тут ещё могут быть идеи...

Comment: Да, про перебор я уже думал, но это как-то не интересно.

Comment: Вы это сами придумали или есть задание?

Comment: @Igor скорее всего важно, все же надо *"Алгоритм должен составить из этого набора нормальное **уравнение**"*

Comment: = Может стоять где угодно, но с обоих сторон должно быть верное уравнение.

Comment: Уравнение решается не по обычному, а немного иначе. Вначале то, что в скобках, а потом просто слева направо. Не учитывая приоритет действий. 3+3*5 будет 3+3 = 6, 6*5 = 30

Comment: @Igor вы правы, на нормальное уровнение не тянет)

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а что это за логика такая решения уравнений?

Comment: Я нашёл такое задание в интернете и пытаюсь его как-то решить, но дойти сам не могу до алгоритма ( разве что перебор). Логика описана в задании. Не знаю, зачем она такая.

Comment: Отметь мой ответ как верное сообщение

Comment: Но это не совсем то, что я ожидал. Всё ещё надеюсь на что-то интересное.

Answer (score 1):

> Java

```
{
  int array [] = /*как нибудь забьешь туда числа*/
  string  a = (array[0] + "=" + array[1] + "+ (" + array[2] + "+" + array[3] + " )" + "*" +array[4]);
  System.out.print(a);

 }
```

> Самое простое
>   В дальнейшем сделай генератор,
>   а так можно в объект все засунуть.